# Getting array_replace_recursive(): recursion detected on magento2.2.2

Tags: magento2.2

When i tried to save config data it show me error like

```
Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Warning: array_replace_recursive(): recursion detected in D:\wamp64\www\mage222\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Type\System.php on line 158
```

[Screensho](https://www.screencast.com/t/19wgEfwk)

any one please guide on this

Comment: have installed without sample data and try to save any configuratino it produce same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue but i tried with installing latest wamp an it is working fine now. It is issue with php version please upgrade php version with the latest one.

Here is my php configuration that i m using for my magento version 2.2.2

```
Apache 2.4.27
PHP 7.1.9
Mysql 5.7.19
Wamp 3.1.0
```

[Screencast](https://www.screencast.com/t/jLV5jXcE0XA0)